# Issue with map function

Tags: python, function, dictionary, variables, python-3.6

Below is the hacker rank code and x is not being mapped to instance args.Can someone please provide me with a reason?https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/python-lists/problem

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    N = int(input())
    l=[]
    for _ in range(N):
        line = input().split()
        cmd = line[0]
        args= line[1:] # <=> here we have 0, 1 or 2 parameters, right?
        """if cmd!= "print":
            cmd += "(" + ",".join(args)+")"""
        #x = ",".join(map(str,args))
        if len(args) == 2:
            x, y = map(int, args)
            if cmd == "insert":
                l.insert(x, y)
        elif len(args) == 1:
            x = map(int,args)
            if cmd == "remove":
                l.remove(x)
            elif cmd == "append":
                l.append(x)
        elif cmd == "sort":
                l.sorted()
        elif cmd == "pop":
                l.pop()
        elif cmd =="reverse":
                l.reverse()
        elif cmd == 'print':
                print(l)
```

Comment: What does "x is not being mapped to instance args" mean? What are "instance args"?

Comment: yes  x is not getting equal to map(int,args). arg refers to line[1:0] .May I know the reason?

Comment: I think you have the problem backwards... `x` ***is*** being set to `map(int, args)`, which means it's a map object and not an int.

Comment: hello sir ,can you please explain in layman terms . I am a newbie to python. Tell me what corrections to be made.

Comment: Just use `x = int(args[0])`. No need for `map` if you only have a single value in your list. And please, clarify your question. It's too hard to figure out what your problem/question is.

Comment: how to add snapshots here sir? what is wrong if i use map function ? If we have a single element in a list we cant use ?

Comment: even after changing the program is throwing run-time error.

Comment: What is the exact error you are getting?

Comment: Please read [mcve] to figure out how to ask a good question.

Comment: x is not getting equal to map(int,args[0]) .Throwing runtime error.

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is with this line:

```
x = map(int,args)
```

This does not work like the line you have in a different branch of your code:

```
x, y = map(int, args)
```

The reason is that the first one binds the name `x` to the `map` call. It doesn't unpack the `map` object to get the single value it will yield. For that you'd need:

```
x, = map(int, args) # note the comma!
```

But if you know that you have only a single value in `args`, there's really no need to call `map` on it at all. Just use `x = int(args[0])` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You have couple of issues in your code.

1. By `x = map(int,args)` (line 16), x becomes a map object. To obtain integer from this map, first convert it into a list and then use indexing. `x = list(map(int,args))[0]` will solve your issue. Or you could simply use `x = int(args[0])`.
2. list has no `sorted` function, change `l.sorted()` to `l.sort()`.